# Defining a date from a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a table of codes and dates that is continuously growing from another source, e.g.

| Code | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RM1377 | a | 30/07/2022 |
| RM1377 | b | 30/07/2022 |
| RM1377 | c | 30/07/2022 |
| RM1377 | d | 30/07/2022 |
| RM1378 | e | 07/08/2022 |
| RM1378 | f | 07/08/2022 |
| RM1378 | g | 07/08/2022 |
| RM1378 | h | 07/08/2022 |

And I want to be able to enter a Code into an input, and then retrieve the date associated with the Code, so that I can query on it.

How can I define DM1377 as always being 30/07/2022, and account for DM1389 potentially being in the table with another date?

I.e. instead of `cruise_date = datetime.date(2022, 7, 30)` I imagine it would be something like `cruise_date = datetime.date(Voyage_date)`

```py
from traceback import print_tb
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

#voyage_id = input('Voyage ID:')

# Retrieve the data and assign headers
df = pd.read_csv("dcl_manifest_20220729.csv", usecols=[0,2,5,6,7,8], names=['Cruise', 'Booking reference', 'First name', 'Last name', 'DoB', 'Cancellation'])
df[['Cruise', 'Booking reference', 'First name', 'Last name', 'DoB', 'Cancellation']]


# Convert DoB column to dates 
df["DoB"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DoB"])

# Define the cruise date
cruise_date = datetime.date(2022, 7, 30)

# Calucate 5 years ago to indentify under 5s
years_ago = cruise_date - relativedelta(years=5)

# Query under 5s and print the output
u5 = df.query('DoB > @years_ago & Cruise == "DM1377" & Cancellation == "No"')
print("Number of under 5s: " + str(len(u5.index)))
```

Comment: what you want is unclear, also please provide your data as text

Comment: You want to remove duplicate rows?

Comment: Thanks and apologies for the lack of clarity. I'm new to coding and Stackoverflow conventions.

Comment: I've updated the description. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The expected output is till unclear to me. Would `df.drop_duplicates(subset='Code').set_index('Code')['Date']` do what you want?

Comment: That might be the way to go.
I'll see what that route reveals
Thanks.